# spark windowing function VS group by performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe done like

```
| id | date      |  KPI_1 | ... | KPI_n
| 1  |2012-12-12 |   0.1  | ... |  0.5
| 2  |2012-12-12 |   0.2  | ... |  0.4
| 3  |2012-12-12 |   0.66 | ... |  0.66 
| 1  |2012-12-13 |   0.2  | ... |  0.46
| 4  |2012-12-14 |   0.2  | ... |  0.45 
| ...
| 55| 2013-03-15 |  0.5  | ... |  0.55
```

we have

- X identifiers
- a row for every identifier for a given date
- n KPIs

I have to calculate some derived KPI for every row, and this KPI depends on the previous values of every ID.
Let's say my derived KPI is a diff, it would be:

```
| id | date      |  KPI_1 | ... | KPI_n | KPI_1_diff | KPI_n_diff
| 1  |2012-12-12 |   0.1  | ... |  0.5  |   0.1      | 0.5
| 2  |2012-12-12 |   0.2  | ... |  0.4  |   0.2      |0.4
| 3  |2012-12-12 |   0.66 | ... |  0.66 |   0.66     | 0.66 
| 1  |2012-12-13 |   0.2  | ... |  0.46 |   0.2-0.1  | 0.46 - 0.66
| 4  |2012-12-13 |   0.2  | ... |  0.45  ...
| ...
| 55| 2013-03-15 |  0.5  | ... |  0.55
```

Now: what I would do is:

```
val groupedDF = myDF.groupBy("id").agg(
    collect_list(struct(col("date",col("KPI_1"))).as("wrapped_KPI_1"),
    collect_list(struct(col("date",col("KPI_2"))).as("wrapped_KPI_2")
    // up until nth KPI
)
```

I would get aggregated data such as:

```
[("2012-12-12",0.1),("2012-12-12",0.2) ...
```

Then I would sort these wrapped data, unwrap and map over these aggregated result with some UDF and produce the output (compute diffs and other statistics).

**Another approach** is to use the window functions such as:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy(col("date")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0L)
```

and do :

```
val windowedDF = df.select (
  col("id"),
  col("date"),
  col("KPI_1"),
  collect_list(struct(col("date"),col("KPI_1"))).over(window),  
  collect_list(struct(col("date"),col("KPI_2"))).over(window)
   )
```

This way I get:

```
[("2012-12-12",0.1)]
[("2012-12-12",0.1), ("2012-12-13",0.1)]
...
```

That look nicer to process, but I suspect that repeating the window would produce unnecessary grouping and sorting for every KPI.

So here are the questions:

1. I'd rather go for the grouping approach?
2. Would I go for the window? If so what is the most efficient approach to do it?

Comment: You should go with the window approach but before select, re-partition the data-frame based on id. This should help in reducing the shuffle operations. val windowedDF = df.repartition(col("id")).select(...)

Comment: so every time a "window" is evaluated I may eventually cause e "resorting" ?
So repartitioning upfront would produce data already partitioned and sorted, so the "window" would be a "no-op" ?
There is a way to "reuse" the same window to emit a more complex, structured data?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it earlier in my code for majority voting. It shuffles the data frame only once and uses it for all the window functions.

Comment: OK thank you very much, I think you should "answer" the question so that is more visible and I can upvote it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the window approach should be a better solution but before using the window functions you should re-partition the dataframe based on id. This will shuffle the data only once and all the window functions should be executed with already shuffled dataframe. I hope it helps.

The code should be something like this.

```
val windowedDF = df.repartition(col("id"))
  .select (
  col("id"),
  col("date"),
  col("KPI_1"),
  col("KPI_2"),
  collect_list(struct(col("date"),col("KPI_1"))).over(window),
  collect_list(struct(col("date"),col("KPI_2"))).over(window)
)
```

---

@Raphael Roth

Here, we are aggregating over a single window. That is why you might be seeing same execution plan. Please see the example below where aggregation over multiple window can be done from one partition only.

```
val list = Seq(( "2", null, 1, 11, 1, 1 ),
  ( "2", null, 1, 22, 2, 2 ),
  ( "2", null, 1, 11, 1, 3 ),
  ( "2", null, 1, 22, 2, 1 ),
  ( "2", null, 1, 33, 1, 2 ),
  ( null, "3", 3, 33, 1, 2 ),
  ( null, "3", 3, 33, 2, 3 ),
  ( null, "3", 3, 11, 1, 1 ),
  ( null, "3", 3, 22, 2, 2 ),
  ( null, "3", 3, 11, 1, 3 )
)

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list).toDF("c1","c2","batchDate","id", "pv" , "vv")

val c1Window = Window.partitionBy("batchDate", "c1")
val c2Window = Window.partitionBy("batchDate", "c2")

val agg1df = df.withColumn("c1List",collect_list("pv").over(c1Window))
  .withColumn("c2List", collect_list("pv").over(c2Window))

val agg2df = df.repartition($"batchDate")
  .withColumn("c1List",collect_list("pv").over(c1Window))
  .withColumn("c2List", collect_list("pv").over(c2Window))


agg1df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Window [collect_list(pv#18, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(batchDate#16, c2#15, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS c2List#38], [batchDate#16, c2#15]
+- *Sort [batchDate#16 ASC NULLS FIRST, c2#15 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(batchDate#16, c2#15, 1)
      +- Window [collect_list(pv#18, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(batchDate#16, c1#14, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS c1List#28], [batchDate#16, c1#14]
         +- *Sort [batchDate#16 ASC NULLS FIRST, c1#14 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(batchDate#16, c1#14, 1)
               +- *Project [_1#7 AS c1#14, _2#8 AS c2#15, _3#9 AS batchDate#16, _4#10 AS id#17, _5#11 AS pv#18, _6#12 AS vv#19]
                  +- *SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._1, true) AS _1#7, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._2, true) AS _2#8, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._3 AS _3#9, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._4 AS _4#10, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._5 AS _5#11, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._6 AS _6#12]
                     +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#6]

agg2df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Window [collect_list(pv#18, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(batchDate#16, c2#15, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS c2List#60], [batchDate#16, c2#15]
+- *Sort [batchDate#16 ASC NULLS FIRST, c2#15 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Window [collect_list(pv#18, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(batchDate#16, c1#14, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS c1List#50], [batchDate#16, c1#14]
      +- *Sort [batchDate#16 ASC NULLS FIRST, c1#14 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(batchDate#16, 1)
            +- *Project [_1#7 AS c1#14, _2#8 AS c2#15, _3#9 AS batchDate#16, _4#10 AS id#17, _5#11 AS pv#18, _6#12 AS vv#19]
               +- *SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._1, true) AS _1#7, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._2, true) AS _2#8, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._3 AS _3#9, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._4 AS _4#10, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._5 AS _5#11, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple6, true])._6 AS _6#12]
                  +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#6]
```

Comment: would that help more?

kpi1DF.repartition(col("short_name")).sortWithinPartitions(col("reading_date"))

Comment: Here we are aggregating as collect list, hence order doesn't matter to if. For further calculations, if order is needed in the list, it might help.

Comment: can you please prove your answer by showing spark plans with and without `repartition`? I made some tests myself: Using 2 Window functions over the same window will not cause 2 shuffles, only 1. Adding a `repartition` did not change the plan at all...

Comment: I have modified the answer to add the plans. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you would need to extract the records based on the counts for a given group.

we can do this in two method.

Method 1:

```
val dedup = inputDF.select(col("A"),col("B"),col("C"),col("D")).groupBy("A","B","C","D").count().as("count")

val snapDF = inputDF.as("baseLoad").join(dedup.as("dedup"),inputDF("A") === dedup("A") && inputDF("B") === dedup("B") && inputDF("C") === dedup("C") && inputDF("D") === dedup("D"),"leftouter").select("baseLoad.*","dedup.count").filter(col("count") > 2)
```

Method 2:

```
val win = Window.partitionBy("A","B","C","D")
val win_count= inputDF.withColumn("row_count",count("*").over(win)).filter(col("count") > 2)
```

Out of these above two method,

- Method 1: 25 Minutes
- Method 2: 4 Minutes

So always, if you have any possible way to use windowfunction over group by then go for window function.