# Apache Spark calculating column value on the basis of distinct value of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am processing the following tables and I would like to compute a new column (outcome) based on the distinct value of 2 other columns.

```
| id1  | id2 | outcome
|  1   |  1  |  1
|  1   |  1  |  1
|  1   |  3  |  2
|  2   |  5  |  1 
|  3   |  1  |  1  
|  3   |  2  |  2
|  3   |  3  |  3
```

The outcome should begin in incremental order starting from 1 based on the combined value of `id1` and `id2`. Any hints how this can be accomplished in Scala. `row_number` doesn't seem to be useful here in this case.

The logic here is that for each unique value of `id1` we will start numbering the outcome with min(`id2`) for corresponding `id1` being assigned a value of 1.

Comment: Can you explain the logic(pattern) to compute outcome column?  1,3 -> 2 then 2, 5 is 1

Comment: @Belwal The logic here in this case is assigning integer values based on the sorted order of distinct combinations.

Outcome is assigned based for each id1 value considering id2 should be unique. If you see for id1 -> 1, id2 -> 1, outcome will always be 1 no matter how many times the same combination gets repeated.

For `id` = 2, there is only one value existing corresponding to `id2`. The min(`id2`) is assigned as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try dense_rank()

with your example

```
      val df = sqlContext
        .read
        .option("sep","|")
        .option("header", true)
        .option("inferSchema",true)
        .csv("/home/cloudera/files/tests/ids.csv") // Here we read the .csv files
        .cache()

      df.show()
      df.printSchema()

      df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
      sqlContext.sql(
        """
          |SELECT id1, id2, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY id2) AS outcome
          |FROM table
          |""".stripMargin).show()
```

output

```
+---+---+-------+
|id1|id2|outcome|
+---+---+-------+
|  2|  5|      1|
|  1|  1|      1|
|  1|  1|      1|
|  1|  3|      2|
|  3|  1|      1|
|  3|  2|      2|
|  3|  3|      3|
+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: With regards to performance how does the dense_rank() perform when it comes to larger set of data.

Comment: Main cost here is the data shuffle and ordering due to windowing. A useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332942/spark-windowing-function-vs-group-by-performance-issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window` function to club(`partition`) them by `first id` and then `order` each `partition` based on `second id`.

Now you just need to assign a rank (`dense_rank`) over each `Window` partition.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df
.withColumn("outcome", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("id1").orderBy("id2")))
```

Comment: I believe the partitioning will enable processing to be done over large set of data.

Comment: It is because of the use case not the data size. I think below links are useful for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404565/sql-server-difference-between-partition-by-and-group-by, https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html